# This code is safe of memory leak?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc

I make a function, this make an operation and after this write on the variable, my question is:
this code is safe ?

There is a sample:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void test(char **out){
    char *f = (char *) malloc(10);
    f = "123456";
    *out = f;
    return;
}

int main(void){
    char *A = NULL;
    test(&A);
    free(A);
    return;
}
```

Comment: `f = "123456";` is memory leak. change to `strcpy(f, "123456");`

Comment: What do you think the line `f = "123456";` is doing?

Comment: Make that strncpy to prevent buffer overflows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
void test(char **out){
    char *f = (char *) malloc(10);
    f = "123456";
    *out = f;
    return;
}
```

The malloc line allocates 10 bytes of memory on the heap.  So at this stage the address of f will be wherever malloc happened to grab a chunk of memory.  For the sake of argument we will say the that this is at 0x10000

Then you assign f the address of a literal string.

The code below prints out what is happening.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void test(char **out){
   char *f = (char *) malloc(10);
   printf("f after malloc = %p\n", f);
   f = "123456";
   printf("f after re-assignment = %p\n", f);
   *out = f;
   return;
}

int main(void){
   char *A = NULL;
   test(&A);
   free(A);
   return;
}
```

Here are some alternative ways to work with strings in C.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static  char* b = "test 2"; 

void test2(char **out){
   *out = b;
}

const char* test3(){
   return "test 3";
}

void test4(char **out){
   *out = (char *) malloc(10);
   strcpy(*out, "test 4");
}

int main(void){
   char *A = NULL;
   char *B = NULL;
   char *C = NULL;

   /* Assign A to the address of a 'global' string */
   test2(&A);
   printf("A is now: %s\n", A);
   /* Don't free this */

   /* return a static string */
   B = test3();
   printf("B is now: %s\n", B);

   /* allocate memory on heap and make a copy of data from a source to that memory location */
   test4(&C);
   printf("C is now: %s\n", C);
   free(C);  /* only C is allocated on heap so free this one */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look more closely into `test()` definition:

```
void test(char **out){
    char *f = (char *) malloc(10);
    f = "123456";
    *out = f;
    return;
}
```

especially those two lines:

```
char *f = (char *) malloc(10);
f = "123456";
```

What this code is doing is simply replacing malloc-ed pointer with pointer to string literal, since that you have memory leak in your program (that is, you have lost your original pointer obtained from `malloc()` call), moreover calling `free()` (within `main()`) in this situation is actually undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

It leaks.

Use `strcpy` for coping the string